# Conditional Strip / Replace based on length of string

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I need to remove the space from a Dataframe of UK postcodes, but only those that contain seven characters.

```
      Client Postcode        lat      long
4             CF1 1DA  51.479690 -3.182190
42640         CF951AF  51.481196 -3.171039
```

Is it possible to add a len() element to:

```
df['Client Postcode'] = df1['Client Postcode'].str.replace(" ","")
```

Comment: Could you add an example with the corresponding output

Comment: Can you please clarify what you need? "seven characters" is something else than a length of seven. Even then, it looks like either all items satisfy the condition for len 7 (making it redundant), or don't only need the operation when having *less* than 7 characters (making it nonsense).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to *conditionally change or create a new column*: 
First, [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where) -
this function lets you return value x or y depending on a condition. In your case, return either the original postcode or the postcode without " " depending on the number of characters.

```py
condition = df1['Client Postcode'].str.len()==7
df1['Client Postcode Clean'] = np.where(condition, df1['Client Postcode'].str.replace("", ""), df1['Client Postcode'])
```

You can use this method to either create a new column (like I did above) or change the original column.

Another way would be to use pandas slicing. You can use the `loc` accessor to find the rows you want to change and overwrite them.

```py
condition = df1['Client Postcode'].str.len()==7
df1.loc[condition, 'Client Postcode'] = df1.loc[condition, 'postcode'].str.replace(" ","")
```

This method is harder to use to create a new column as it will return NaNs for rows that do not satisfy the condition.

Answer (score -1):

Just to offer up one more alternative, one could iterate through the dataframe and scrub the post code as in the following code snippet.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['CF1 1DA', 51.479690, -3.182190], ['CF951AF', 51.481196, -3.171039]], columns=['Client Postcode', 'Lat.', 'Long.'])

for i in range(len(df.index) - 1):
    if (len(df['Client Postcode'][i]) == 7):
        df['Client Postcode'] = df['Client Postcode'].str.replace(" ","")

print(df)
```

Hope that helps.

Regards.

Comment: Masking would be much more efficient rather than iterating over all rows.